# jQuery scrolling detection

Tags: jquery

I've got some code to display a "Go to top of page" message if I scroll down a bit on a page.   Everything works on it but I'm trying to understand how the jQuery works.

The following is the top line of the jQuery call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

without a link to the jQuery library 
I get the error message

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

which bit or bits of the 212 pages of the jQuery library defines this **$** 
?
Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/neeklamy/RpPEe/ here

Comment: yes , Jquery plugin will define $ sign .

Comment: Yes MrBuggy, that's the code I'm running, I'm trying to figure out how it works

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking about. The `$` alias is defined here https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/jquery.js#L38

Comment: I want to know what the pure JavaScript is that does the scrolling, detects that I've scrolled down the page, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The $ variable is defined in the [jQuery source file](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/jquery.js)

```
window.$ = jQuery
```

is where the assignment is made.

If you're examining the jQuery source code it'd be a good idea to get the build environment setup.

For that you'll need to download [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and the [jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/archive/master.zip)

unzip the file and open a command terminal and cd to the folder

at the command line you can then type:

```
npm install -g grunt
npm install
grunt build
```

Comment: ta, I'll have a look at that tonight